# What is the correct way to get the stackoverflow.com URL for an answer via the API?

Tags: support, api, answers

A while ago I made a little *"Recently answered on Stack Overflow"* sidebar widget for my homepage. Currently this works by filtering answers out of the user feed however I thought I'd update it to make use of the API instead.

I can successfully retrieve `/users/{id}/answers` however there doesn't seem to be a field for an answer's URL so is the way to do this just to concatenate

```
"http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/" + question_id + "/" + 
  answer_id + "#" + answer_id
```

This is fine but it doesn't include the URL-friendly version of the question title so if I wanted that in the URL would I have to generate it myself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to generate any links back to "proper" SO yourself.  The most any of the API methods will give you is (relative) links to other API methods.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why isn't this included as part of the api? It seems like a common enough use case (for example, I need to get the url of an answer object that I just got from the api).

Answer (score 3):

As of version 2.0 of the API, answers can return a `link` field in the response, which can be returned in the response by creating a filter that includes it:

[image]