# OBSOLETE - Stack2Blog - Turning your answers into blogs (For "sale")

Tags: app, website, python, obsolete

**Stack2Blog for Sale**

Hi everyone!

Since we're working on a few other projects, we haven't worked on Stack2Blog in a while.

We still think it can be useful, especially with the rise of platforms like Posterous, which make blogging much simpler.

That said, if anyone else is interested in taking over the project, let me know (edanm@btlms.com).

The source is already open-sourced, so taking over the project == us giving you the domain name + (small) db.

Drop me an email if you're interested.

---

**Previous News**

Updated to work with the 1.0 api (hacked PyStack since there isn't an updated version yet).

We've [released the source code](http://bitbucket.org/edanm/stack2blog) under the MIT license. Check out the code section below.

[**<del>Stack2Blog</del>** (Dead link)](http://www.stack2blog.com) now supports all the trilogy sites, not just Stack Overflow.

## Stack2Blog is looking for beta testers

If you like this application, we'd love your feedback on how we're doing. Please [<del>check out our site</del> (Dead link)](http://www.loopycode.com) and give us any feedback you can.

## What is Stack2Blog

Have you ever written a long, detailed answer on StackOverflow, and wanted to publish it on your blog/website? If you're like most longtime users, you probably have many great answers scattered all over the place, with no way to manage them.

Stack2Blog is a web service that helps you manage which of your StackOverflow answers you've migrated into blog posts and other places.

Visit the homepage, enter your Stack Overflow user id, and you'll be presented with a list of all your Stack Overflow answers. You can then copy the answer (formatted for easy WordPress pasting), and we'll remember that this answer has already been copied to your blog.

If you like this app, please support us by upvoting.

If you have any ideas for features you'd like to see, please post them below.

#### Beta

Stack2Blog is in beta stage. Please help us by trying it out and letting us know what you think. Any and all feature requests/bug reports/criticisms are welcome (post them as answers on this page).

#### Screenshot

[image: Stack2Blog - Screenshot]

#### Site main page

[<del>www.stack2blog.com</del> (Dead link)](http://www.stack2blog.com)

#### License

The source-code will soon be released under an open-source license.

### Contact

This app is being written by Edan Maor and Yuval Cohen.

Visit Edan's blog, [<del>LoopyCode</del> (Dead link)](http://www.loopycode.com), or follow him on twitter [here](https://twitter.com/edanm).

Follow Yuval on twitter [here](https://twitter.com/cohenyuval).

### Code

This app is written in Python/Django. It uses Django 1.1.

It uses the great [Py-StackExchange](https://stackapps.com/questions/198/py-stackexchange-an-api-wrapper-for-python/) wrapper to access the StackApps api.

The code is licensed under the MIT license, and you can find it on our [BitBucket page](https://bitbucket.org/edanm/stack2blog). Enjoy!

### Version

Current version - v0.2
API version - 0.9 (Updated - 24.06.2010)

### StackList

Visit our StackList entry and give us a star here: [<del>Stack2Blog on StackList</del> (Dead link)](http://stacklist.quickmediasolutions.com/view_app.php?id=23)

**Support us by upvoting if you like the idea. Thanks :)**

Comment: +1 yes, I occasionally have wanted this.  It'd be *really* slick if you could roll this into a WordPress/Drupal/whatever module that could be accessed directly within each site's admin panel.

Comment: I really like this idea!!

Comment: You should be able to use general blogging apis to push these into a Wordpress/Drupal/Blogger (etc) draft.  It would be great if the draft had some intelligent formatting, using a well-designed template.  I would totally use it!

Comment: Edan - great idea, most of my feedback is on the aesthetic side of your implementation. Otherwise, nicely done.

Comment: Just to say - from your code, you could use StackAuth to query site information rather than hard-coding the site list, especially now that the Gaming SE has entered private beta, with more coming soon it seems! :)

Comment: @Lucas: That's a good point, I wasn't totally clear on the right way to do that. Thanks!

Comment: Tried it with my StackOverflow user id 114029 and got an error.

Comment: @Leniel Macaferi: You're right, it should work now. We weren't updated to the latest api version. Thanks for letting me know!

Comment: If anyone is interested in continuing the project, let me know.

Comment: @EdanMaor I'm not sure if you're working on his, but it seems to be broken - it seems to pick up a random Stack Overflow answer instead of my SU answer

Answer (score 10):

It would be much more convenient if you implemented automatic posting using a blogging API. It looks like most popular blog engines support the new blogger API (Wordpress, Blogger(duh), Drupal, MoveableType, etc...)

[WordPress Docs](http://codex.wordpress.org/XML-RPC_Support)

[Drupal Docs](http://drupal.org/node/295)

Answer (score 5):

For some answers, the answer doesn't make a lot of sense without the question, so having the option to include a part of the question would be great (at least displaying the text in the page so the poster can select what's relevant).

Comment: there's a link to the question on the posting page

Answer (score 3):

Product design question:

- Would you like an answer's comments to also appear within the blog post's draft?
- Would you like these comments replicated as comments of the blog post?
- Or are they best left unused in the blog post as they have no place there?

Let me know your preferences.

Comment: I personally would rather the comments weren't there - from the usage scenario you put forward in the question (person blogging own answer/question), they would add little. (IMHO, of course.)

Comment: For some answers, the comments might be important in a 'good to know' way - they're not part of the answer itself, but they might be useful for someone using the information in a slightly different context than the person who asked the question.

Comment: it might be interesting to see the comments for additional information, but i wouldn't automatically include them

Answer (score 1):

My feedback:

- a really useful and excellent idea, thank you!
- easy (enough) to use
- since blog posts are generally more highly formatted than SO answers, auto-publishing might be convenient but is not critical (at least to me)

Keep up the good work!

One suggestion: offer openid integration so i don't have to keep looking up and typing in my user id every time i visit the site

Answer (score 1):

I would realy like a two way sync (I know that requires v2 API). That way I can augment my answer on my blog with images and more explanation and have that fed back into Stack overflow :)

Answer (score 1):

Love the idea but I get these errors everytime.

---

Internal Server Error
The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator, webmaster@stack2blog.com and inform them of the time the error occurred, and anything you might have done that may have caused the error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.

Additionally, a 500 Internal Server Error error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

Comment: Can you give me an example of something you did that cause this error? I'm looking to reproduce.

Comment: I pressed on post to blog on got the 500 errors every time and site.