# Stack Monthly - Best questions in the month

Tags: app, python

### About

This website allows user to unearth gems which are hidden due to popular community questions. This is done by only showing most voted questions asked in that month.

It allows a user to follow a tag, or set of tags by subscribing to feed.

#### Screenshot

[image]

#### License

MIT

#### Source Code

https://github.com/hitezh/StackMonthly

#### URL

http://stackmonthly.com/

#### Platform

Tested for compatibility on the latest Firefox, Chrome and Internet Explorer.

### Contact

Creator: Hitesh Sarda
whois at hitesh dot in

### Code

To extract and store questions
 - Python
 - [Py-StackExchange](https://stackapps.com/questions/198/py-stackexchange-an-api-wrapper-for-python)
 - Sqlite

**for the website**
 - Python
 - [BottlePy](http://bottlepy.org/)